# Simply jQuery prob

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this blob of code for a vertical jquery slider.

Basically all I need is that when #expert_button is clicked, it slides down, then when it is clicked again, it slides back up.

I've literally tried everything with all manner of ridiculous/ineffective results, including continually sliding down, everything happening all at once on page load. you name it.

Before I take up another choice of hobby - any chance of a pointer as to what I'm doing wrong? Would be MASSIVELY appreciated!

```
$('#expert_button').toggle(function() {
$('#expert_slider').animate({
    top: '+=245'
    }, 458, 'swing', function() {
}),
$('#expert_slider').animate({
    top: '-=245'
    }, 458, 'swing', function() {
    });
});
```

Comment: which version of jQuery you are using ?

Comment: ^ Check here http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/

Comment: oh I'm using 10... is that a bit new for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

Hey include the migrate library. you can download it from jquery.com and include it just like you include the jquery library. Include migrate.js and your code will work

Comment: Thanks mate - didn't seem to kick it into action for some reason? probably me doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Make use of this `clickToggle` plugin

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.clickToggle = function (func1, func2) {
        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function () {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
$('#expert_button').clickToggle(function () {
    $('#expert_slider').animate({
        top: '+=245'
    }, 458, 'swing', function () {})
},

function () {
    $('#expert_slider').animate({
        top: '-=245'
    }, 458, 'swing', function () {});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - this one probably a bit hectic for a rookie like me

Answer (score 0):

If all you're after is a simple sliding toggle, jQuery has a "shortcut" method for that: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Here's a sample derived from the API ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6FpX/)):

```
<button id="the-button">Toggle</button>
<div id="the-panel">
    This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs. You
    should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
    your life. Congratulations!
</div>
<script>
    $('#the-button').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#the-panel').slideToggle("slow");
    });
</script>
```

If you include an easing library, you can also change the easing function to something more interesting.